# Exception handling in c++ how do I implement it here

Tags: c++, exception

I just created a program in c++ about adding matrices but I just dont know how to exception handle the part where to choose a number from 1 to 10 so that the user can only choose a number from 1 to 10 and if he puts a wrong input in it shows an error message and is asked to input a number again

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int r, c, a[10][10], b[10][10], sum[10][10], i, j;

void matrix(string s) {

    cout << "Enter number of rows (between 1 and 10): ";
cin >> r;

cout << "Enter number of columns (between 1 and 10): ";
cin >> c;
    
}

void storeValues(string s) {

    cout << endl << "Enter elements of " << s <<  " matrix:" << " " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i) 
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        {
        cout << "Enter element " << i + 1 << j + 1 << " : ";
        
            if (s == "1st") {
                cin >> a[i][j];
            
        }
        else
            cin >> b[i][j];
        }
    
    

}

void addMatrices() {

    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
    sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];

}

void displayResult() {

    cout << endl << "Sum of two matrix is: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i) 
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) 
        {
        cout << sum[i][j] << " ";
        if (j == c - 1)
            cout << endl;
        }
    

}

int main()
{
 string s = "1st";
 matrix(s);
 storeValues(s);
 s = "2nd";
 storeValues(s);
 addMatrices();
 displayResult();

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer not to throw exceptions when handling User or Operator input; it irritates them.    Instead use an outer loop that can handle the invalid input.  Exiting a program due to invalid typing means that the User or Operator has to reload, and relaunch your program, hopefully typing the input correctly.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know but how can I use an outer loop because I dont think I ever used it before

Comment: You could use `while (entry is not valid) {/* ask user for input and validate */}`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily make a function that handles bounded input for you, something like:

```
int bounded_input(int lower, int upper, std::string message) {
    int r;
    bool valid = false;
    cout << message << " (between " << lower << " and " << upper << "): ";
   
    do {
        cin >> r; // NOTE: You will want to check for invalid input like "three" ...
        if (r < lower || r > upper) {
            cout << "Invalid, please enter between " << lower << " and " << upper << ":";
        } else {
            valid = true;
        }
    } while (!valid);
    return r;
}
```

Then you can simply call this for all of your bounds:

```
int row_bound = bounded_input(1, 10, "Enter row bounds");
```

Comment: Side note: You may want additional armour on `cin >> r;` to catch wise guys who type in stuff like "Three" that can't be parsed at all.

Comment: you sure would! This feels like something the OP can look into, i will add a comment.

Comment: alright I just error handled if the user types in a wrong integer input what if he writes a string what should I do 
  cout << "Enter number of rows (between 1 and 10): ";
  cin >> r;
  while (1 > r > 10) {
   cout << "Error! please input a number between 1 and 10" << endl;
   cin >> r;
  };      This is what I did so far

Comment: @hgka1000 `while (1 > r > 10)` doesn't do what you think it does. You need to write it as  `while (1 > r || r > 10)` instead. And don't forget to *validate* that `cin >> r` is even successful to begin with, otherwise the value of `r` will be *indeterminate*. Try this instead: `do { if (cin >> r) { if (r >= lower && r <= upper) { break; } } else { cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_liimit<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); } cout << "Invalid, please enter between " << lower << " and " << upper << ":";
} while (true);`